# BackgroundImage object of style class is not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code. When I run it, the gradient in the background doesn't get updated.

```html
<html>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
     <body style="text-align: -webkit-center;">
     <div id="coo">
     <h2 class="display-3">Which color gradient do you want?</h2>
     <h3 class="display-4" style="font-size:2rem">Color 1:</h3>
     <input type="text" id="color1" class="form-control" style="width:20%;margin:20px">
     <h3 class="display-4" style="font-size:2rem">Color 2:</h3>
     <input type="text" id="color2" class="form-control" style="width:20%;margin:20px">
     <button onClick="grad(color1,color2)" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width:20%;margin:10px"> Submit </button>
     <div id="result" role="alert"></div>
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      function grad(c1,c2){
       
       let a=String(c1.value).toLowerCase()
       let b=String(c2.value).toLowerCase()
       console.log(a)
       console.log(b)
       document.getElementById('coo').style.backgroundImage="linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, yellow);"
    
      }
     </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

I was trying to get a similar effect as this link:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_gradient-linear_diagonal

Comment: `onClick="grad(color1,color2)"` <-- what is color1 and color2? You really should not rely on elements being referenced by their id in global scope.

Comment: Your code does not work because you added a `;` into your style. `yellow);"` <-- that ; is the reason why

Comment: @epascarello im new to this, why shouldnt we rely on elements being referenced by their id in global scope? is it for security reasons??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done great, also I get from it how to update `linear-gradient` using javascript that for that.
There is just a typo while updating the `linear-gradient` of `;` which is inside the string literal.

You have to correct the typo at the last of the statement-

From this-

```
document.getElementById('coo').style.backgroundImage="linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, yellow);"
```

To this -

```
const direction = "to bottom right"; // which you can take input from user as drop down 
document.getElementById('coo').style.backgroundImage=`linear-gradient( ${direction} , ${a} , ${b} )`;
```